# Echo each record of a query result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm attempting to extract some data from a database and echo each result. The code below is code that I took from a textbook and then tried to modify to fit my own website that is hosted locally. I cannot see where I'm going wrong, no error messages are shown, just a blank screen when I run the scrip.

```
<?php #script 9.4 view top 5 recipients
// This script exctracts data from db and then displays each record in a table

    DEFINE('SYSPATH','FOO');

    require '../application/config/database.php';

    require 'mysqli_connect.php';

    $q = "SELECT alert_recipient as NAME
          FROM alert
          LIMIT 5;
          ";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

    // $dbc database connection comes from required mysqli_connect.php       

    if($r) 
        {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            echo $row['name'];
        }

        }


    else {
        echo "<p>ERROR</p>".mysqli_error($dbc);
        }

?>
```

Comment: blank screen is most likely an error you need to log. Enable error logging, follow the error log.

Comment: I would guess `... AS 'name'`

Comment: You need to find your error.log and read the last entries, see what the error and line is.

Comment: I have to take that back. it's perhaps also blank because you don't output anything.

Comment: @James what is error log? Can I get the script to display them? I thought I did with mysqli_error?

Comment: PHP error log shows PHP errors, warnings and notices (ie what went wrong and pointer as to where, what script, etc). The mysqli errors are specific to mysql (so if you had PHP syntax or other issues it would not show up on a mysqli error output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks okay except for your `echo $row['name'];`, note that you are selecting `NAME`, uppercase.

Change your echo statement to be:

```
echo $row['NAME'];
```

because field names quoted within `$row` array are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment yet)

Maybe the script works but there is no results to display. Check your database.